# Unable to read a list in Jquery

Tags: javascript, list

I am trying to read (access values) a list in Jquery like this:

```
    var list = { length: 0 };
    var subTypeId = "";
    list = '<%: Model.lstDC_TAn %>';
    alert('list = ' + list);
    for (var j = 0; j < list.length; j++) {
    subTypeId = list[j].DCSubTypeId;
    alert('subTypeId = ' + subTypeId)
```

The alert for list shows that its a "Generic list", however, the subTypeId is always undefined. I have checked in the controller. The list is not null and the property that I am trying to access (DCSubTypeId) is also present inside each element in the list.

EDIT:

```
 public List<DC_TAn> lstDC_TAn { get; set; }
```

Comment: you mean list."length" ??

Comment: because `list` is an string literal.. remove the `''` enclosing it like `list = <%: Model.lstDewCard_TypeAssociation %>;` assuming it is returning a valid array format

Comment: There is no ' ' enclosing the list. Its just an alert.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is flawed. As it stands, you're dealing with raw string. Such code:

```
list = 'Generic list';
alert(list[0]);
```

Will alert "G", as string is array of characters. Character/String in JavaScript indeed has no property called "DewCardSubTypeId".

You need to first change the server side code to output proper object, e.g.

```
public string lstDewCard_TypeAssociation
{
    get
    {
        return "[{\"DewCardSubTypeId\": 5}, {\"DewCardSubTypeId\": 100}]";
    }
}
```

Then get rid of the quotes when assigning it:

```
list = <%: Model.lstDewCard_TypeAssociation %>;
```

Then your code should work.

Comment: Ok thanks,  but I don't understand what I am returning in the get property. I also need the set property.

Comment: @Adi you have to return a string that is valid array of objects. Can't really explain much better, sorry. You might need to ask separate question about how to convert server side C# data structure/class to client side JavaScript object, in there post your C# code, what you have so far and what you have tried.